# What are examples of creative uses of restaurant print design paraphernalia?

Tags: print-design, branding

I was recently asked to design all the print design paraphernalia for a *tapas* restaurant of a great friend of mine. That would include a menu listing all the *tapas* and wines, a glass pad, a place mat, a promo flyer and all the things my friend could use to engage his customers in a funny, creative experience. This includes both print design and social media strategic planning. His restaurant is an old, rustic warehouse that was used to store salt made in the canals of my hometown in Aveiro, Portugal.

What are examples of creative uses of restaurant print design? How are restaurant managers using print design to engage their customers? Pardon me in advance for my rusty english.

Comment: Check [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/search?q=restaurant&x=0&y=0)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about additional paraphernalia besides what you've listed? Or do you want to know what to *do* with the place mats once they're designed? It's "creative uses" which is confusing me.

Comment: sounds like he wants both the items/premiums/collateral themselves *and* inspiration about branding.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking both for branding inspiration and additional paraphernalia. Are there any fancy glass pad layouts out there? Any cool table accessories you may know? How are restaurant managers using print design to engage their customers?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Stack Exchange Q&A format is not well suited to answering this type of question. As explained on the FAQ page, "Brainstorming or idea gathering" questions don't really work well here. If you have specific design questions, you will receive better answers if you ask each one individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are examples of creative uses of restaurant print design?

http://www.underconsideration.com/artofthemenu/